# nth repeated element in a list

Tags: python, list, repeat

I am interested in more pythonic and performant approach to the below solution.

```
def nthFrequent(arr,n):

    d = dict((x, arr.count(x)) for x in set(arr))

    value = sorted(d.values(), reverse=True)
    # Pick nth repeated element
    nthrepeat = value[n-1]

    for (key, val) in d.iteritems():
        if val == nthrepeat:
            return key


a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,92,3,2,35,9,2,43,4,9,9,9]

print nthFrequent(a,2)
```

The above code would return 2 as two is repeated 3 times after 9 which is 4 times.

I am looking more elegant way of using lambda, I tried the following by not getting required results.

`max(((item, a.count(item)) for item in set(a)), key=lambda k: k[1])[0]`

The above one will get max repeated value, ie. 9.

How do I get the second one or nth one?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do with lambda here, but if just you want to find an element which repeats exactly N times it is better to use `Counter` or calculate occurrences manually (without calling `count`). Your current solution is O(N^2), but you can solve this problem in O(N).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward with collections.Counter.  However, be aware that this solution will only return one of 3 or 4 if the `n` value is changed to 3 since there would be a tie in that case.

```
import collections

def nthFrequent(arr,n):
    return sorted([(v, k) for k, v in collections.Counter(arr).items()], reverse=True)[n-1][1]

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,92,3,2,35,9,2,43,4,9,9,9]

print nthFrequent(a,2)
```

Also worth noting: a list of tuples sorts by the 0 index element of the tuple.  So you can use a tuple with `(count, value)` and just return that value.  There is no lambda needed in the sort.

If you really want to do this without imports then even this would be a faster implementation:

```
def nthFrequent3(arr, n):
    d = {}
    for v in arr:
        if v not in d:
            d[v] = 0
        d[v] += 1

    return sorted([(v, k) for k, v in d.items()], reverse=True)[n-1][1]
```

And if you do decide in the future to use imports, then give itertools a look too.  It has some handy tools as well

```
def nthFrequent2(arr, n):
    for i, (value, _) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(sorted(arr))):
        if i == n - 1:
            return value
```

Comment: Thanks @sberry. My intention is try to avoid collections.

Comment: @paddu Any specific reason here?  You asked for something more "pythonic and performant" and this is both.

Comment: Well, certainly it is performant and pythonic. But, I was looking something without using any import of modules. Thanks for taking the pain and explaining this to me.

Comment: @paddu I am interested to know why you want to do this without using imports?  I mean, they are part of the standard library for a reason.

Comment: @paddu, if you are worried about polluting the namespace, you can just import the one function you need: `from collections import Counter`

Comment: @sberry - This is out of my curiosity and not to use any library and playing around with lambda. I am newbie with Python,

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a one-liner, the following should work:

`return sorted(((item, a.count(item)) for item in set(a)), key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)[n-1][0]`

While the above uses more Python language features, I actually prefer the readability of your original code.

As a side note, in your original code, you should `return key` because you currently are trying to print a function that doesn't return a value.

If you care about ties, as @sberry mentioned, you can do:

Get smallest value when count is the same:

```
return sorted(((item, a.count(item)) for item in set(a)), 
    key=lambda k: (k[1], k[0]), reverse=True)[n-1][0]
```

Get largest value when count is the same:

```
return sorted(((item, a.count(item)) for item in set(a)), 
    key=lambda k: (k[1], -k[0]), reverse=True)[n-1][0]
```

Comment: Thanks, return was something I messed up as I was trying between lambda and the original code.

Answer (score 2):

Letting *N* be length of `arr`, this line:

```
d = dict((x, arr.count(x)) for x in set(arr))
```

goes through a number of steps on the order of *N*<sup>2</sup>. First, `arr` is traversed to find its unique elements (worst case is that every element is unique). Second, *for each* unique element, the *entire list* is traversed again to count how many times that element appears. Your one-line solution is also on the order of *N*<sup>2</sup>.

That's a lot of unnecessarily repeated steps. You only need to look at each element of `arr` once. In one step, you can:

- check if you've already seen this element
- increment the counter for this element

Like this:

```
counter = {}

for x in arr:
    if x not in counter:
        counter[x] = 0
    counter[x] += 1

pairs = sorted(counter.iteritems(), key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)

key, count = pairs[n]
return key
```

In the worst case, where every element is unique, this code goes through a number of steps on the order of *N*log(N)* due to the sort. (The pass through `arr` is on the order of *N* because `dict` lookups in Python are on the *amortized* order of 1.)

Comment: `counter[x] = counter.get(x, 0) + 1` avoids needing an if condtition.